# do i need sitemaps for each subdomain for site?

Tags: subdomain, sitemap, google-crawlers

I have a site built using different smaller sites hosted on subdomains. There are a lot of links between the subdomains and root domain, so all pages can be reasonably reached.

Do I need a separate sitemap for each of the sites? One of the smaller sites is a WordPress blog, for which generating a sitemap is easy. However, some of the others don't have a sitemap generator.

Do I really need a sitemap for each of the sites or can I expect google to crawl all the pages as long as there is at least one link to them?

Answer (score 0):

"If it is necessary" is a question I will other to discuss. However, you have to create a sitemap.xml file each subdomain/domain. (You can't have URLs from multiple domains/subdomains in the same sitemap.xml file)

Comment: thanks, still not clear whether there is an advantage to having a sitemap for every subdomain ... if google can reach everything... why do we need one?

Comment: as for 2018 google says otherwise, eg, that you CAN have multiple subdomains in one sitemaps https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en